# How can I make table cell borders transparent?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365

How can I make table cell borders transparent? Or the alternative: how to control cell-spacing in top, bottom, left, right cell directions individually?

The headings and the following rows exist in the same table. I want to add gap between the blue cells and adjacent blue cells but not blue cells and the heading above:

[image]

I can use colored borders but it would only allow solid color backgrounds and require a change of border colors every time the background is changed.

Edit:

[image]

I want the gaps indicated by red lines but leave out ones indicated by blue.

Comment: Unclear: Where *exactly* are the gaps to be added?

Comment: @harrymc Updated for clarification.

Comment: You can increase cell height in Table Properties, tabs Row and tab Column, for the specific row 1 and column 2. If that's enough for you.

Comment: Change the cell border to background color with border line weight, but the line weight cannot be set customization.

Comment: @harrymc But that would increase the size of a cell instead of adding spacing between 2 adjacent cells no?

Comment: @Lee I mentioned the limitations after the second image already. I want to go for a limitation free method so that it can be used as a template.

Answer (score 0):

As per the tutorial below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgMN-hHft-c&ab_channel=eHowTech

1. Click on the table until you spot the cross at the top-left corner
2. Toggle "Table Design" from the main toolbar, which should appear when you clicked at the cross emerged at the top-left table corner
3. Go to "Borders" on your right and click it in order to populate dropdown list
4. Select "No borders" and it should work. Make sure, that a whole your table is selected. Otherwise the borders will disappear only for one cell.

[image]

Comment: I already have this result in image 1. Now I want the spacing between cells but with control of each individual side's spacing.